# Thunderbird indicator in 16.04 LTS Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, indicator, thunderbird

I recently started using Thunderbird again, but I cannot seem to get that indicator icon, i.e. **minimize it to tray** so that I could receive new message updates.

d.conf editor shows it should be OK:

[image]

Has it been removed from 16.04?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the Add-On MinimizeToTray revived (MinTrayR) - this seems to work for me on Ubuntu running XFCE. Havent tested it with Unity and or Gnome-Shell so far.

Comment: Doesn't. Installed successfully, but nothing happens on closing/minimizing - Unity.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Actually, it works - kind of. There is no indicator, and the launcher shows Thunderbird as closed, but it's actually opened and the (1) notification appears upon receiving mail. However, there's no sound or pop-up.

Comment: mh - sounds better then nothing but far away from perfect :/

Comment: Works fine now with the bell indicator. Weird. Took three restarts.

Comment: Great..  Glad it is working now for you